# Troubleshoot needed :TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple

Tags: python, tuples, typeerror, writetofile

The error mentioned above occurs when we run this code. We've been crackin at it this past few hours but nothing seems to work.

Could someone please point us in the right direction.

```
import math 
myList=[] 

with open("data_2.txt") as f: 
    for line in f:
        myList.append(tuple(line.rstrip().split()))
dic = {}
for index, ele in enumerate(myList):
    key=index+1
    val_2=float(ele[1])
    val_3=float(ele[2])
    dic.update({key: (ele[0],val_2,val_3)})
    for i in range(len(dic)):
            power= 5//(val_2)
            P=pow(0.5,power)
            cal_grams=val_3*P
            if cal_grams<100:
                outfile = open("Element_Shortage_List.txt", "w")           
                outfile.write(ele+ "   " + float(cal_grams) + "\n")
                outfile.close()
```

Comment: You will need to show at least part of your `data_2.txt` too – it's very hard to help otherwise.

Comment: I don't know the content of the file but try to replace this line: outfile.write(str(ele)+ "   " + float(cal_grams) + "\n")

Comment: `ele` is a tuple what would you suppose `(1,1) + "string"` would do?

Comment: `myList` is a list of tuples. In the `for` loop you put such tuples into `ele` . So, where you write `ele+ "   " ` you concatenate a tuple and a string filled with spaces. Hence the error. Read the traceback not just the message, it tells you what happened explicitly.

Comment: Thanks y'all. it working now when we do outfile.write(str(ele)+ "  "+str(cal_grams)+"\n")

Answer (score 0):

As Error message tells you, you concatenate a tuple with a string.

If you really want to write the following line to your file, use string formating:

then this line:

```py
outfile.write(ele+ "   " + float(cal_grams) + "\n")
```

become

```py
outfile.write(f"{ele}   {float(cal_grams)}\n")
```

More details about f-strings: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone especially Menno Holscher.

it finally reads when we do

```
outfile.write(str(ele)+ "  "+str(cal_grams)+"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you: you can't add a tuple and a str type, so convert the tuple to str. Like this.

```
import math 
myList=[] 

with open("data_2.txt") as f: 
    for line in f:
        myList.append(tuple(line.rstrip().split()))
dic = {}
for index, ele in enumerate(myList):
    key=index+1
    val_2=float(ele[1])
    val_3=float(ele[2])
    dic.update({key: (ele[0],val_2,val_3)})
    for i in range(len(dic)):
            power= 5//(val_2)
            P=pow(0.5,power)
            cal_grams=val_3*P
            if cal_grams<100:
                outfile = open("Element_Shortage_List.txt", "w")           
                outfile.write(
                str(ele) + "   " + str(float(cal_grams)) + "\n")
                outfile.close()
```

If you're on python3 you should check out f strings.
It's very simple. An example would be:

```
outfile.write(f"{ele}    {float(cal_grams)}\n")
```

Comment: yeah bro (str(ele)+ " "+str(cal_grams)+"\n") managed to fix it